# $R^2$ vs. significance of the other variables

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, panel-data, r-squared

I am currently working with panel data to see if there is correlation between sustainability and performance in the energy and materials sector of the S&P500.

I ran the regression twice, one with the logarithm of MarketValue (=MarketValue.WINS.LOG) and one without (=MarketValue.WINS).

The outcome is different and I really wonder if I should go for the log MarketValue or not?

The regression with Log MarketValue has a 0.1 -0.2 higher $R^2$, but the other variables are not really significant anymore.

The "normal" regression has more significant variables but the $R^2$ is not performing as well, as the one in the log-MarketValue-regression.

I don't know which model is the right one and thought, may you could help me out. :)I attached the 2 regressions, so you can take a closer look for yourself.

Thanks in advance and have a nice weekend. :)

**"NORMAL" MarketValue**
[image]

**LOG MarketValue**
[image]

Comment: It is meaningless to compare $R^2$ after applying a nonlinear transformation to the response variable.  Your concern ought to focus on looking at evidence of how suitable each model is as a useful and accurate description of the data.  That involves going through the entire regression analytical pipeline repeatedly: data cleaning, exploratory data analysis, model identification, review of diagnostics, testing & sensitivity analysis, and interpretation.  Obviously that's not something we can describe in a single post here on CV! Search our site for more on all these topics.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is problematic to pick a statistical method based on the significance of covariates.

Assuming that you're doing a linear regression, one of the model assumptions is that model residuals are normally distributed. You can assess this by making a QQ plot with the model and a histogram of the response variable.

Researchers often log-transform variables to improve model fit and meet model assumptions. If the histogram and QQ plot do not suggest a normal distribution, you can try a log transformation (or other types of transformations). Importantly, you should then make sure to visualize the log-transformed model's QQ plot and histogram to assess normality.

After settling on the most appropriate model structure, then you can interpret the model fit and significance of explanatory variables. However, keep in mind the other assumptions of linear regression.